# MongoDB query that looks for documents with lowercase values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

Is it possible to make a MongoDB query that searches a field for *completely* lowercase string values?

Something like this pseudo query perhaps?

```js
{ address: { $eq: { $toLower: "$address" } } }
```

...that would return docs with data like: `{ "address": "123 main st" }`, but **won't** return docs like `{ "address": "123 Main St" }`, or is such a query not possible with MongoDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the clarification, yes what you want is possible and you were pretty close with the original syntax.  Try something like the following:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $toLower: "$address"
      },
      "$address"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground link is here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FLEd5D8JYha).

There may be some extra considerations depending on language, collation, etc. But this should serve as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use aggregation pipeline that makes specific fields lowercase and than does matching against them, for examples look at
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/#example
and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#examples

On large datasets this way of querying would not be efficient, but for one time queries may be useful.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I saw that `$toLower` operator in their documentation, and that is precisely want I want to do, and why I included it in the pseudo example I gave, but I don't know how to cast a field as lowercase _in the query itself_, and do the comparison in the first place. 

I know I need to do something like `str.toLowerCase() === str` but I have no idea how to translate that into a pipeline stage or regular query. `item: { $toLower: "$item" }` returns a lowercase value in a `$project` stage, but doesn't do a lookup on it.

Comment: When I try to do something like `item: { $toLower: "$item" }` as a query, MongoDB just says `unknown operator: $toLower` which tells me that `$toLower` must be restricted to `$project` operations only.

Comment: Please see the next comment using find, it seems valid query example that does this.